# get previously selected node on a TreeView WebControl

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, web-controls

I'm using a treeview to display my full site hierarchy. When I select a node, I put a ImageUrl with a check symbol on the selected node. But when I select another Node, the image on the previous Node keeps present. 
What I want is to reset de ImageUrl of the previously selected node. Is there any way for accessing the previously selected Node?

Comment: Can you use a simple `if` statement?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give me more details?

Comment: Well, I imagine that you are using an event handeler, in which case you could put an `if` statement inside to check what is selected, and remove everything else.